# My 12V DC Vending Machine motor rotates 1 extra 360 degree rotation sometimes. What could be the reasons?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

have main board which has motor control circuit and has row and column to control the row and column of the vending machine.

I have made changes in motor in two ways:

A. I have attached an image for circuit diagram
[image]

In this design I have some pros and cons

PROS: 1. It stops at its home position after one rotation
2. It detects row and column of the machine

CONS: 1. Sometime it does not stop at its home position or take more than 1 rotation

B. I have attached an image of other diagram

[image]
In this design also I have some pros and cons

PROS: 1. It stops perfectly at its home position after one rotation.

CONS: 1. It does not detect ROW

Please suggest What should I follow and what should I made changes in the circuit.

Here is the video

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N7ItjeU84JiDAOquAD6SGHkVWufDT40K

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VX9yncrm6pcr1IBQsNvVZ1yR0UMflJKA

Comment: it rotates extra because it is programmed to do so

Comment: You've programmed 3.1 sec delays but your comments suggest you intended 2 second delays. Are you seeing ~50% extra rotation?

Comment: I have tested it with different time delays. Forgot to clear the comment.

Comment: Not 50% extra. It rotates little bit forward like 10% extra with 3.1 sec delay,

Comment: Why have you chosen 2 seconds? Won't a shorter delay give the rotation you want?

Comment: I have not chosen 2 seconds. It was just written in comments only.

Comment: I just want to rotate the motor from the home location to the home location when I give signal one time. But i do not know what time delay should I use?

Comment: Have a look on this video
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15CmMVI410zq1Vc2Wl7yseq9n4T8Q1rMm

Comment: what are the NO and NC pins used for?

Comment: find out ... use an ohmmeter to find out when the limit switch closes or opens

Comment: @sugandhasharma, what are the results of the switch testing?

Comment: jsotola when switch is not pressed then C is connected to NC and when switch is pressed, C is connected to NO.

Answer (score 1):

> "It rotates little bit forward like 10% extra with 3.1 sec delay,"
>
> "I just want to rotate the motor from the home location to the home location when I give signal one time. But i do not know what time delay should I use?"

More than 2.0 and less than 3.1! If 3.1 sec gives 110% rotation, then you need
(100/110)*3.1 = 2.818sec to get 100%.

I realize that your 10% extra is an estimate and not accurate to 3 decimals, but I'd use 2.82 as a starting point and tweak it up or down until you get the amount of rotation you want.

Remember that timing a motor to get distance will inherently be inaccurate due to inconsistencies in the motor acceleration rate and rotation speeds, due to variations in its temperature and the power supply voltage, and load, but this should get you started. For long term accuracy, i.e., if you need it to always come back to a fixed position, you'll need some position feedback, which may be as simple as flag on the motor shaft interrupting a photocell. And even that will have *some* degree of inconsistency due to coasting speed when you shut the power off, but at least those error won't accumulate.

Update:

> 2.82, My motor rotates 10% less every time and change its location in every rotation

Right - 2.82 was a first approximation. If that is too small, try splitting the difference between 2.81 and 3.1. If that ends up too small, then split the difference between it and 3.1; or if it was too big, try splitting the difference between 2.1 and it. Do that a few more times until you have an acceptably close value.

Then read what I said about accumulating errors. The Arduino doesn't ever know what the motor position is so it can't correct for any overshoot or undershoot. If you need accuracy and repeatability, you'll have to add some kind of position sensing, or switch to using a stepper motor and drive the number of steps that makes one full rotation (and it would still have to be started from a known position).

Comment: What position feedback? Motor has limit switch but I could not control the limit switch. Can you help me in this?

Comment: With 2.82, My motor rotates 10% less every time and change its location in every rotation

Comment: @sugandhasharma Probably, controlling the motor the way you try only works more or less properly for multiple rotations. Due to the number of coils/magnets the motor has stable positions at specific angles. Stopping at positions between those angles might not work

Comment: @Sim Son If you know about it please let me know. I have attached the circuit block diagram and video too. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15CmMVI410zq1Vc2Wl7yseq9n4T8Q1rMm

Comment: I feel you might be building a solution that will only work for a short period of time. The time you calculate will work for the environmental conditions you have right now. As temperature and humidity and age of the motor change, friction will change, this will likely have an impact on the amount of time that the motor needs to be active to get.to a desired position.  You should seriously consider an approach that says "I'm here" when the motor reaches the desired position. This is mentioned @jrobert answer as "position feedback" you should investigate(search) it.

Comment: In this motor, there is attached a micro limit switch but it is not working,
Common of switch is connected to Ground through MOSFET module
NO is connected to ground through MOSFET module.
It does run the motor but does not stop on its home location.

Comment: If that is the case, then you need to fix it. Either fix the switch on the motor (probably not easy) or build a separate one that works alongside of the motor.

Comment: Another problem that I forgot to mention in my comment above (but is mentioned in the answer) is accumulation of error. Let's say you can stop the motor perfectly within 0.1mm of where it is supposed to be using time alone. That's pretty good, but after just 10 cycles it will be 1 cm out of place. After 100 cycles it will be a full 1cm out of place and so on. As jrobert mentioned position feedback can avoid this problem.

Comment: Does anybody know the reason? It is really very important for me.

Comment: If the switch circuit is not stopping the motor, check the switch circuit itself. Does it actually interrupt the power? If it stops the motor, but lets it coast beyond home, you may need to use a slower motor speed to reduce the coasting.